# Combinatoric "Rotation" Cycle

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

Suppose we have a set of numbers, $C=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, and we have the function $\pi(x)$ that moves all elements to right by $x$ places iteratively, starting in the first element. If there are not $x$ more elements to the right, it goes back to the start.

For example, if $C=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then $\pi(1)$ applied to $C$ is $\{2,3,4,5,1\}$

Now for example, $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ then $\pi(4)$ applied to $A=\{5,3,1,5,\dots\}$ so $\pi(4)$ applied to $A$ is $\{5,3,1\}$.

Now consider the set $Y=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $n\ge3$. How many $x$'s there are such that $\pi(x)$ applied to $Y$ doesn't not have the elements $1,2,3$ at the same time and are not repeated sequences?

What I mean by repeated sequences:

$C=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ , $\pi(1) = \pi(6)$, so it's counted as 1.

Comment: Do the elements $1$, $2$, and $3$ have to appear in that order? Or can they be anywhere in the set, as long as they are in the set?

Comment: No, they just need to be in the set, because as I said in my 4th line, {2,3,4,5,1} = {1,2,3,4,5} in this case

Comment: it basically gets stuck in a cycle, in the example I gave after I apply the shift of 4 to the 1st element (1) and make that shift a few times, I get back to 1 without stoping at 2 for example, so 2 is not part of pi(4)

Comment: Can you avoid the double negative of "doesn't not have"? Do you want it to have all 3 elements? Or at most 2 of the 3 elements? Or at most 1 of the 3 elements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer is $\infty\ \forall\ n\ge3$.

Reasoning:

First note that there always exists an $x$ for any values of $n\ge3$ such that an application of $\pi(x)$ will include $1$, $2$, and $3$, namely $x=1$. Then note that an application of $\pi(n+1)$ has the same effect as applying $\pi(1)$, and same with $\pi(2n+1)$, $\pi(3n+1)$, and so on. So we get that $x\equiv1\pmod n$, of which there are infinitely many $x$'s that satisfy this congruence.

Comment: I said iteratively starting from the first element, so for example X={1,2,3,4,5,6} and i apply a shift of 4 (pi(4)) I apply that shift in the first element (1) and i get 5, then I apply a shift of 4 to 5 and i get 3, then I apply the shift of 4 to 3 and I get 1 again, and from now I get stuck in a cycle of 1,3 and 5

Comment: I have edited my answer. See if there are any errors.

Comment: It is reasonable to assume that $x < n$ for this question to be meaningful.

Comment: I guess that the problem that I copied was not stated totally, i guess that since this a combinatorial problem, the question might be all x's such that when applied those 'rotations' give diferent sequences of numbers, hence the {2,3,4,5,1} not equal to {1,2,3,4,5}, I'm really sorry and I'll correct right now

Comment: so there might be some x<n that give the same final sequence. 

Of courese, if the sequence starts repeating itself, say {1,2,3,1,2...} for example we just assume it as {1,2,3}

Answer (score 0):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, write out your working and thought process to demonstrate where you're at.)

**Hint:** Show that $\pi(k) (Y_n) = \left\{ 1 + t\gcd(k, n ) {\large{\mid}}  0 \leq t \leq \frac{n}{\gcd(k,n) - 1} \right\}$.
E.g. In your example, $ k = 4, n = 6, \gcd(4,6) = 2$ and we have $\pi(4) (Y_6) =\{ 1, 3, 5 \}$.

(depending on the intending phasing with the double negative)
Hence, if you want it to have element $2$, then $ \gcd(k, n) = 1$, so there are $X$ of them.

> $X = \phi (n)$.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know how to start showing the hint ):

Comment: @JoséPedroFerreira What have you tried? If you're stuck, write out your working and thought process. E.g. Can you show that it's true when $ \gcd(kin) = 1$? Why would we have hit all of the values?

Comment: Just a quick thing, before I move on. I corrected my question. The answer you have assures that those x's do not return the same sequence?

Comment: @JoséPedroFerreira A) Avoid the double negative. Please clear that up. B) What is a "repeated sequence"? That was a new term that you threw in. C) I have no idea what you're asking for, so .... I do not know.

Comment: I was at this moment explaing it, check it out :)

Comment: @JoséPedroFerreira My suggestion/feedback is that you should play around with this question more, as opposed to just relying on others to spoon-feed you answers. I'm guessing that you haven't done so, else you've have made some basic observations like how things can loop around, and what kind of sets we can get. Once you do that, proceeding with the question will be much more clear (and hopefully immediate).

Comment: With what I did, I concluded very few things. But here's what I've done so far:

The first thing I did was to think {1,2,3,...n} as {0,1,2,n-1} so it becomes easier to think the problem in elementary modular arithmetic

Now I must discover the solutions where 0,1,2 will appear after I apply those rotations. I need to solve this congruencies:

a x = 0 mod n |
a x = 1 mod n |
a x = 2 mod n |

where a is the 'rotation jump'(?) and x will be number of times we apply that 'jump'

Comment: here I take that the ax=0 mod n has solution, therefore the element 1 will always be in the set and "I don't need to care about it anymore"


then I have:

1. a x = 1 mod n
2. a x= 2 mod n

for this to have solution gcd(a,n) must divide 1 and 2, since only '1' can divide 1 and 2, gcd(a,n)

So we have to find all a's such that a is coprime with n. And here I'm stuck

I made a little python programm to check if your answer was correct (totient of n), and yes it's seems to be the correct answers. But I have no idea how to get there with what I just did

Comment: @JoséPedroFerreira Using modular arithmetic, do you agree that $\pi(k) Y_n = \{ 1 + Tk \pmod{n} \}$? If yes, can you show that this set equals $ \{ 1 + t\gcd(k, n ) \pmod{n} \}$. If you're stuck, at least show that one set is contained in the other.